# Zend with Oracle: Queries not working properly

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework

I am very new to zend framework and have a project for it with Oracle as its db. After so many difficulties I was able to set-up zend, and then make it up connected to the db.

So that's the intro; so lets move to actual problem. Everything will be fine, if... if...

I am able to run queries using abstract class methods. I m using the guestbook models, mappers as base and placed my models in same way those were set-up. Initially I was unable to know whether I was connected to db or not. So for that I used: `oci_connect();`.

It helped me to know that I am really connected to oracle db. But this is just for testing. Then I used `Zend_Db::factory(...options...).` It too worked fine using `$db->fetchAssoc()`, etc. methods. But this too is not my requirement as I dont want to write hard coded queries. I want to execute queries running either using:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory($config->database);

$select = $db->select()->from('clients');
$stmt = $select->query();$result = $stmt->fetchAll();echo "<pre>";print_r($sql);echo "</pre>";die;
```

OR, using Abstract Class internal methods like:
   $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll();
   fetchAll()

The last 2 mentioned ways are not fetching data... and I am totally lost where to find solution for these both ways.

application.ini details:

```
resources.db.adapter = "oracle"
resources.db.params.dbname = "//11.11.11.11/RAC"
resources.db.params.username = "abc"
resources.db.params.password = "abc"
```

Comment: what error are you getting when you use fetchAll ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have established working functionality with your database. You can query the database and get expected results. But you would prefer different syntax for interacting with your database.

Comment: Mona Cheikhna : When fetching data using $select = $db->select()->from('clients');$stmt = $select->query();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
                                                                            Error Message: 942 ORA-00942: table or view does not exist SELECT "clients".* FROM *"clients" . The 'clients' table exist. I have database schema.

Comment: Mona Cheikhna : And when using $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll(); processing keeps on going on and on, with an error message at last:Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Oracle.php on line 417

Comment: Yes RockyFord. Absolutely Correct. Can you find me some different way or tutorial, to have an idea, or I can learn multiple way of fetching data.

Comment: How many rows are in the table?

Comment: There are only 61 records.. Phil

Comment: New Update: $select = $db->select()->from('clients');$stmt = $select->query(); $result = $stmt->fetchAll(); now working. And I think $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll(); is also working but now I m having new error. It is                                                                                                                                   Message: A table must have a primary key, but none was found                                                                         but the table has a primary key :( so it is really working or not I donno knw.

Comment: you can set the identity of the primary key in your DbTable class by setting `protected $_primary = 'column';`. You also may have to set `$_sequence = false` because Oracle apparently dosen't support auto incrementing keys. Have you tried using the PDO version of the Oracle adapter, that might provide better functionallity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I'll take wack at this.

Establish application.ini settings, [Notes on Oracle Adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.adapter-notes.oracle):

```
resources.db.adapter = "oracle" or "PDO_Oci"
resources.db.params.dbname = "//11.11.11.11/RAC"
resources.db.params.username = "abc"
resources.db.params.password = "abc"
//if you are only using one DB go ahead and set default adpter to true.
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

Setup DbTable classes

```
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_Member extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    //name of dtabase table
    protected $_name = 'member';
    //name of column with primary key
    protected $_primary = 'memberid';
    //primary key auto-increment? True for yes false for natural key
    protected $_sequence = FAlSE;
```

in your DbTable classes or classes that are children of them you'll have access to Zend_Db_Table_Abstract methods. I know you're currently using mappers but the info may come in handy and provides simple demostrations as the default db adapter is already available.

```
//I like the select() method when querying against a table because select() provides
//automatic quoting of most values. select() can be used to built fairly complex queries.
//This method will either fetchAll() in the table or fetchRow or Rowset against provided values
public function fetchAllMember($column = NULL, $value = NULL) {
        $select = $this->select();
        if ($column != NULL) {
            $select->where($column . '= ?', $value);
        }
        $result = $this->fetchAll($select);
        return $result;
    }
```

if you're not using select() you may elect to use the quoteInto(), quote() or qouteIdentifier() methods. These require a reference to the db adapter.

```
public function deleteMember($memberId) {
        //reference the available adapter and quote the values into the sql statement
        $where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('memberid = ?', $memberId);
        $this->delete($where);
    }
```

it also works without the adapter when not using the quote methods.

```
public function addMember(array $memberData) {
        $data = array(
            //array of data
        );
        $this->insert($data);
    }
```

When the abstract methods are available, the table_row methods are also available and my favorite of these the save() method which works as an insert and an update method on a single row.

```
public function saveAlbum(array $data) {
        //I like to use object notation when possible
        $dataObject = (object) $data;
        //create row
        $row = $this->createRow();
        //if id is present as array key the row will be updated
        if (array_key_exists('id', $data)) {
            $row->id = $dataObject->id;
        }
        //else a new id will be assigned and a new row created
        $row->name = $dataObject->name;
        $row->artist_id = $dataObject->artist_id;
        $row->year = $dataObject->year;
        //insert or update row
        $row->save();
        // return the row of data
        return $row;
    }
```

When working outside of the classes the extend abstract accessing the db is a little different.

```
//in controller or models or other classes the default adapter is easily available.
$db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
```

with the adapter available you can use [Zend_Db_Select()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) or [Zend_Db_Statement()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html) to build and execute queries.

```
//Zend_Db_Statement()
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM bugs');
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

//Zend_Db_Select()
$select = $db->select()
             ->from('products'); 
$stmt = $db->query($select);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

This is by no means comprehensive, but does give the high lights of Zend_Db. I hope it helps

Comment: though you answer is fruitful, but I donno how my select()->where()-> etc. way started working. And I started development using it only as I was having no option to bypass this method. I too like this select() method way as it is similar to codeigniter active pattern, n I am good at CI. But getDbTable()->fetchAll(); is still a big question on my side. Newayz thanks for ur help :)

Comment: in what context are you using ` getDbTable()->fetchAll();`? Is it in a mapper, dbTable, model or controller?